# How to redact a dynamic environment variable GitHub Actions?

Tags: github-actions

I have a GitHub Action where I am dynamically retrieving an AWS Access Key ID & Secret Access Key. I set those as outputs, and then pass those into my next step where I set them as environment variables, and call my action.

```
- name: Set Terraform Output to GitHub Actions Output
  id: terraformOutput
  run: |
    echo ::set-output name=codeDeployAccessKeyID::$(cat terraformOutput.json | jq -r . codeDeployAccessKeyID.value)
    echo ::set-output name=codeDeploySecretAccessKey::$(cat terraformOutput.json | jq -r .codeDeploySecretAccessKey.value | base64 --decode | gpg -d -q)
- name: CodeDeploy
  env:
    AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID: ${{ steps.terraformOutput.outputs.codeDeployAccessKeyID }}
    AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY: ${{ steps.terraformOutput.outputs.codeDeploySecretAccessKey }}
  run: aws-code-deploy
```

This works perfectly, however, when I look at the logs for my GitHub Action, I can see the AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY environment variable in plain text.

This is not very secure at all.

In past projects when I was using GitHub Actions Secrets, these values would be redacted and replaced with `***`. Again, that is not a solution here tho since the secrets can change, and I need to be able to dynamically pull them in the action.

Is there a way to redact these dynamic outputs and mark them as secure or sensitive somehow to allow them to be passed in as environment variables, but not have them shown in the GitHub Actions log?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could mask it manually like

```
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY = "access-key"
echo "::add-mask::$AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY"
```

Or you could use the `@actions/core` package GitHub provides to [mask the secret](https://github.com/actions/toolkit/tree/main/packages/core#setting-a-secret):

```js
const core = require("@actions/core");

core.setSecret("access-key");
```

Comment: This worked perfectly! Thank you. Made a quick edit to include example code for how to use the `@actions/core` package to set the secret. Always better to include details within the answer itself instead of relying on an external link. Thanks for the answer.

Answer (score -1):

There is an [API for manipulating Github Actions secrets](https://docs.github.com/en/rest/actions/secrets) . You could create dummy secrets for AWS and update them in the first step through the API, then access the up-to-date secret on the next step the same way you would access a static secret.

There are many actions on the market, doing this for you already, as [GitHub Actions Secrets Creator](https://github.com/marketplace/actions/github-actions-secrets-creator), [Manage Github Secrets](https://github.com/marketplace/actions/manage-github-secrets) or [Set Secret Action](https://github.com/hmanzur/actions-set-secret)